# How to create event on Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I tried to do it but I didn't succeed. The event need do when a new channel is opened in Discord, you will write a message on a channel that opens a new channel

```
client.on("channelCreate", channel => {
  const newchannel = client.channels.find('id', channel)
  newchannel.send("New Channel!'")
});
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `channelCreate` event returns a `GuildChannel` so there's no need to manually search for it.

```js
client.on("channelCreate", (channel) => {
    channel.send("Channel created!").catch((error) => {
        console.error(`Couldn't send message to ${channel.name}. | ${error}`)
    });
});
```

Also, you are using the find function wrong. This is how you should use it:

```js
client.channels.find(channel => channel.id == "ChannelID").send("Hello World!");
```

Alternatively you can use:

```js
client.channels.get("ChannelID").send("Hello World!");
```